# Not saving all data in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

Im doing a simple save, and its not entering all the data. I have two models, message and emailmessage. The message table is getting populated ok, but the emailmessage table, is only getting the foreign key message_id. Below is the code. Anyone notice anything unsual?

EmailMessageModel

```
class EmailMessage extends AppModel {

var $name = 'EmailMessage';

var $belongsTo = array('Message');

var $validate = array(
    'user_name' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'Please enter your name'
    ),
    'user_email' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Please enter your name'
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'rule' => 'email',
            'message' => 'Please enter a valid email address'
        )
    )
);

function beforeSave()
{
    $this->data[$this->name]['verified'] = 1;
    return true;
}
}
```

MessageModel

```
class Message extends AppModel {
var $name = 'Message';

var $actsAs = array('Containable');

var $hasOne = array(
    'EmailMessage' => array(
        'className' => 'EmailMessage',
        'foreignKey' => 'message_id'
    ),
    'TwitterMessage' => array(
        'className' => 'TwitterMessage',
        'foreignKey' => 'message_id'
    ),
    'FacebookMessage' => array(
        'className' => 'FacebookMessage',
        'foreignKey' => 'message_id'
    ),
    'VideoMessage' => array(
        'className' => 'VideoMessage',
        'foreignKey' => 'message_id'
    )
);

var $belongsTo = array('Fact' => array('className' => 'Fact', 'foreignKey' => 'fact_id'));

function beforeSave() {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->name]['ip']) && empty($this->data[$this->name]['ip'])) {
        $this->data[$this->name]['ip'] = getRealIp();
    }
    return true;
}

function __findVerified($options=array()) {
    $query = array(
        'conditions' => array(),
        'contain' => array(
            'FacebookMessage' => array( 'conditions' => array('FacebookMessage.verified' => 1) ),
            'TwitterMessage' => array( 'conditions' => array('TwitterMessage.status' => 'verified') ),
            'EmailMessage',
            'VideoMessage',
            'Fact'
        ),
        'order' => 'Message.created DESC'
    );

    // Merge the query with any additional options passed in to the function
    $options = Set::merge($query, $options);

    // Do we want the query only? Then just return the query.
    if($this->isQuery($options)) {
        return $options;
    }

    // If not, return the records
    return parent::find('all', $options);
}
}
```

EmailMessageController

```
class EmailMessagesController extends AppController {

function register(){

    Configure::write('debug', 2);

    if (isset($this->data)){

        $this->EmailMessage->saveAll($this->data);

        debug($this->data);

    }

    $this->layout = "ajax";
    $this->render("add");

}

}
```

Data

```
    Array
(
[Message] => Array
    (
        [fact_id] => 3
    )

[EmailMessage] => Array
    (
        [user_name] => Joe Bloggs
        [user_email] => here@there.com
    )

)
```

Thanks

--Mark

EDIT:

Here is the tables

EmailMessages - http://pastebin.com/zXTT5VHd

Messages - http://pastebin.com/Rd1MP0CJ

Comment: Why not post the code here instead ?

Comment: Sorry, i'd rather use pastebin for large chunks.

Comment: also, tbh, the code paste on here isnt what it could be. Would I be better to paste it on here?

Comment: Try posting a smaller code sample, maybe it will help.

Comment: Try setting atomic to true, as this will at least force it to be a single query, which is a bit easier to deal with.
http://api.cakephp.org/class/model#method-ModelsaveAll

Comment: Hi David, still no luck. How can i see the SQL?

Comment: Best thing to use is DebugKit http://www.ohloh.net/p/cakephp-debugkit this will show a tab in the top right of the app, which you can see pretty much every single bit of info you'd ever need :)

Answer (score 1):

Is the name of the problematic table email_messages? I noticed that in your model user_name and user_email must not be empty. But your tables allows *NULL* values for these fields.